# Button Link Does Not Invoke Handler in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to use a [React Bootstrap Button Link](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#buttons) to call a handler

I'm not sure why the click when clicked is not invoking my handler:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { HelpBlock, Button, Table } from 'react-bootstrap'

export default class Users extends Component {
  render() {
    const { users } = this.props
    return (<span><UserList list={users} /></span>)
  }
}

export class UserList extends Component {
  render(){
    const { handleResetPassword, list, resetPasswordError } = this.props
    const userList = list && list.map(
        (user, i) =>
          <User
            handleResetPassword={handleResetPassword}
            key={i}
            resetPasswordError={resetPasswordError}
            user={user}
          />)

    return(<Table responsive>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First</th>
          <th>Last</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>{userList}</tbody>
    </Table>)
  }
}

export class User extends Component {
  render() {
    const { uuid, firstName, lastName, email } = this.props.user

    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{firstName}</td>
        <td>{lastName}</td>
        <td>
         <HelpBlock disabled={this.props.resetPasswordError ? true : false}>{this.props.resetPasswordError}</HelpBlock>
          <Button
            bsStyle='link'
            onClick={this.props.handleResetPassword}
          >
            reset password
          </Button></td>
      </tr>
    )
  }
}
```

*I also noticed that on page load, it's auto hitting my handler for some reason, I didn't even click the button.  I see the `console.log("handleResetPassword invoked!")` being hit...not sure why*

**UsersContainer**
(I will be refactoring this code to remove duplication so FYI in that setState in the try/catch)

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import * as UserAsyncActions from '../actions/Users/UserAsyncActions'
import Users from '../components/Users/UserList'

class UsersContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      resetPasswordError: null
    }

    this.handleResetPassword = this.handleResetPassword(this)
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.props.allUsers(this.props.token)
  }

  async handleResetPassword() {
    // e.preventDefault()
    console.log("handleResetPassword invoked!")
    try {
      await this.props.resetUserPassword()
      if(this.props.hasResetPassword){
        // show successful message (set message here)
        return
      }
    }
    catch(err) {
      this.setState({
        resetEmailValidationState: 'error',
        resetPasswordError: !this.state.hasResetPassword && 'reset failed'
      })
    }

    this.setState({
      resetEmailValidationState: 'error',
      resetPasswordError: !this.state.hasResetPassword &&
      'reset failed'
    })
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <Users
        handleResetPassword={this.handleResetPassword}
        resetPasswordError={this.state.resetPasswordError}
        users={this.props.users}
      />)
  }

}
export const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isRequestingAllUsers: state.user.isRequestingAllUsers,
  hasResetPassword: state.user.hasResetPassword,
  users: state.user.users,
  token: state.auth.token
})

export const mapDispatchToProps = {
  allUsers: UserAsyncActions.allUsers,
  resetUserPassword: UserAsyncActions.resetPasssord
}

export { Users }
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UsersContainer)
```

Comment: Why aren't you using redux to dispatch an action from User instead of wasting your time passing down the function through several components?

Comment: I am, I'm dispatching via a thunk action but I prefer to centralize my behavior in the container.  I do not like  putting handlers in my dumb components period....that's just the way it is and it's good practice to do so AND I TDD so it makes complete sense to start at the container level to TDD a new feature.  Trust me when you TDD, you'll understand why...it forces good design.

Comment: Well, dumb components in React are supposed to be of the functional type. All of those could probably have the class based React component parts removed from them.

Comment: yea but I like the class, I know what you mean...I may change those. I use flowtype so they need to be classes

Comment: so I still have a major issue, the one I started with which is when I click the button, nothing happens, it's not hitting my handler that I pass down.  It's like the onClick isn't even registering or something else

Comment: I say that blindly of course. I just heard that's the way to go, I'm not sure exactly the reasoning behind it, but should prob look that up, since I'm offering advice on it -_-

Comment: Try removing the export default statements from UserList and User. You dont need them on all of them, as you are only importing User back into your container. User is the parent of those two, so those children dont need to have export statements. There is where I think your problem lies. You need to pass the function down into Users then UserList then User

Comment: Could be wrong about not needing the export statements on those two children, but still, the function has to be passed into Users first.

Comment: the function is being passed as a prop from UserList to User, look closely: <User
            handleResetPassword={handleResetPassword}
            key={i}
            resetPasswordError={resetPasswordError}
            user={user}
          />)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you malformed your `bind()` in `UserContainer`, It should be `this.handleResetPassword = this.handleResetPassword.bind(this)`.

Comment: I do not want my handler logic in Users.  I am centralizing it in my container.  In my world behavior stays central and defined in the container and keep dumb components free of behavior as much as possible..  I also TDD behavior starting at the container level

Comment: handleResetPassword is defined in the Container and passed down and I'm already binding that handler to _this_ at the container level; look at my container's constructor

Comment: Is this code typo `this.handleResetPassword = this.handleResetPassword(this)` when you write your code here?

Comment: hmm I don't see the typo there

Comment: another thing that's odd is it's calling handleResetPassword on page load

Comment: oh sh**....I totally missed bind().  So I'm calling it on the construction of this container which is why it's calling it

Comment: can you amend your answer (remove everything) to just to say that I've malformed my bind() and also I still have an outstanding issue of when I click the button, it's not invoking my handler

Comment: Ok I'll do it, before that do you mind trying to call `this.props.handleResetPassword` inside `handleResetPassword = () = { // here }` method in your `User` component?

Comment: I mean in `UserList` component.

Comment: sure I'll try moving the handler to the User component (although I'm going to want to move it back later just FYI)

Comment: eh yea if I put this into my UserList it works handleResetPassword = () => {
    console.log("handler hit!!!!")
  }

Comment: crap duh found it I wasn't passing it from Users to UserList.  OMG I NEED SLEEEEEP

Comment: I told ya you weren't passing it from Users. =) glad it worked out.